# Bash Bulk Rename Folders with 3-Digit Prefix and Delimiter

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I have a series of folders that I'd like to rename with a prefix number and delimited text.  For instance:

```
% ls
blue        green   keyboard    pictures    red     tango       yellow
flyer       gum     orange      pop         runner  videos
```

rename to:

```
% ls
001-blue        002-green       003-keyboard    004-pictures    005-red     006-tango       007-yellow
008-flyer       009-gum     010-orange      011-pop     012-runner      013-videos
```

I am using the following to rename except that after 009, I then have 0010, 0011, and so on.  I would like to keep prefix numbers to 3 digits.

`% i=0; for x in *; do; mv "$x" "00$i-$x" ; i=$((i + 1)); done`

I know the problem is in the `mv` command because of the hard-coded `00` in the destination name, but I don't know how to change that to a 3-digit exclusive destination name with the `$i` variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `printf "%03d-%s\n" $i, $fname` will get you started.  Just echo the results to terminal, until you are sure it is working as needed, the `your stuff script | bash` to rename all of them. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -le '$cmd = sprintf( "mv $_ %03d-$_", ++$i ) and system $cmd for @ARGV;'
```

To do a dry run and print the intended commands without renaming any files, use `print` instead of `system`, like so:

```
perl -le '$cmd = sprintf( "mv $_ %03d-$_", ++$i ) and print $cmd for @ARGV;'
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

See also the docs for [`sprintf`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf).